# Mysql SQL_DELAY not working

Tags: mysql, linux, delay, slave

I'm attempting to have a MYSQL slave delay behind master for approximately 10 minutes.  This is so I can revert a potentially catastrophic query before it propagates to my slaving machines.

When running the following:

> show slave status \G

I can se that the SQL_Delay is set correctly.  However, when I write or update master, the changes seem to update the slave immediately.  Google has failed me while searching for this issue.  I'm hoping somebody can help.  Thanks.

[image]